# How to retrieve all data from three tables according to groupby of second table's field value using Laravel eloquent query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models with some methods like

1.Employee Model

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
       'employee_no','card_no','inactivedate', 'activedate', 'status',
     ];


    public function office(){
        return $this->hasOne(EmployeeOffice::class);
    }

    public function section(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hrm\Section');
    }

}
```

2.EmployeeOffice Model

```php
class EmployeeOffice extends Model
{
  $fillable = ['employee_id','section_id','line_id','join_date','gross','confirm_date'];

public function employee(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
 }

public function section(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Hrm\Section');
}

}
```

3.Section model....

```
class Section extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','description','status'];

  //
}
```

i need **all inactive employee information** according to the employee inactive date(from employee model) as well as **their all office information** from EmployeeOffice model and must be **groupBy according to section_id** which is (section_id as foreign key) available in EmployeeOffice model.

For that i have to go with some condition like  ..

```php
 Employee::where('inactivedate','like','%'.$date.'%');
*And need all data from office and employee table 
*need section name and grouped by as section name from section model

***please suggest me how can i solve this problem ***
```

Comment: What does the date look like? Normally you got the format YYYY-MM-DD. If you want to all dates like in a month you can use `like`. If not you should use the normal `where` and `=`.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: sorry, but still not

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: @liqSTAR employee and employeeOffice model has one to one relationship but employeeOffice to section model has one to many relationship.

Comment: so that i have added section model here

Comment: @liqSTAR sorry this question may be retrieve data from multiple/there table's

Comment: But if the `section_id` is the foreign key in your `EmployeeOffice` then you just need to join the table `sections` to retrieve all the data. Then this should be the solution you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved my problem by this...**

```
       if(Input::has('start') && Input::has('end')){
            $start = Carbon::parse(Input::get('start'))->startOfDay();
            $end = Carbon::parse(Input::get('end'))->endOfDay();

            $start = $start->format('Y-m-d');
            $end =  $end->format('Y-m-d');

           EmployeeOffice::query()->whereHas('employee',function ($query) use ($start,$end){
                $query->whereBetween('inactivedate',[$start, $end])->where('status',0);
            })->paginate()->groupBy('section_id');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = Section::with(
    array(
        'employeeOffice' => function(
            $query->with(
                'employees' => function(
                    $query->where('employees.inactivatedate', 'like', '%'.$date.'%'
                    )
            )
        )
    )
)
->get();
```

This should give you an array to every `section_id`. In this array are the `employeeOffice`s (1:n-Relationship). The second query with `with` will fetch for each `employeeOffice` the employee who sits in it.

But if you defined the relationships right, this should do the trick to:

```
Section::with('EmployeeOffice.Employee')->get();
```

[Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: please review this question because i have edit and described my problem with details.

Comment: I will Check your Edited question

Comment: Edited my answer according to the sections join.